# Pycharm and IDLE

Tags: pygame, pycharm

Why doesn't the PyCharm work when I try to open image using pygame it just says: 'Couldn't open ... image'.
And when I copy same program in IDLE it works fine.
(I fix path so PyCharm is importing pygame, but still it won't open image).

Comment: Did you check source path ?

Comment: i did. It can import pygame but it cant open theese images, full error                                      `bg = pygame.image.load('Game/forest.jpg')
pygame.error: Couldn't open Game/forest.jpg`

Comment: Try a bullet proof check. create a brand new script and put these images in the same directory. 
````py
import pygame
import os
pygame.init()
bg = pygame.image.load('forest.jpg')
print(os.getcwd()) # to ensure
````

Answer (score 0):

Probably check your source path. Actually PyCharm and IDLE are just editors so there is no difference in relative pathing. Absolute paths may cause a problem. If you cant find the issue please share the error message.